# IOS/Swift: Set text of label with IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, label

I am having trouble with the elementary task of setting the text of a label.

The label is wired from storyBoard to an IBOutlet. When I try to set the text of the label with the following code it gives the error: Expected Declaration

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!


var someText: String = "Some text"
self.myLabel.text = someText
```

If I change `self.myLabel` to... `let self.myLabel`... it gives error: Expected pattern

What is the proper syntax to set the label text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the given example you cannot use the property of outlet example .text directly outside of any method.
    to do it correctly you need to create a method or you can use predefine method for example viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

          self.myLabel.text = someText

    }

or

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

          setTextOfLabel()

    }

func setTextOfLabel(){

  self.myLabel.text = someText
}
```

Comment: I got it to work on its own in viewDidLoad but when there is another statement such as self.myLabel.text = "hello" and self.myLabel.numberOfLines = 1 it gives error  'Argument passed to call that takes no argument

Comment: Finally got both text and numberoflines to work by moving both to separate function (your setTextOfLabel) called from viewDidLoad though don't understand why could not have both statements in viewDidLoad

Comment: Does that error message ring a bell?  As mentioned there is no error once I moved the code to a different method.